# iSeries Access v5.8 - SQL to update records for one customer except latest record?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm relatively new to SQL and need to put together an UPDATE statement for a table.

(I start with a SELECT statement, and once I'm sure that is working I then create the UPDATE statement.)

So I have one table CONTRACTS, each line represents one contract. A customer can have multiple contracts on the table, but the contract numbers always increment by one.

I want to select all the contracts except the latest (i.e. largest contract number) contracts for each customer. (These are the lines I will be updating)

I've tried

```
SELECT * From Contracts T1
WHERE EXISTS
(Select * from Contracts T2 WHERE
T1.CUST = T2.CUST AND T2.CONTRACTNUMBER < MAX(T1.CONTRACTNUMBER))
```

But the green screen tells me the use of `MAX` is invalid.

I must be getting my syntax wrong - any help?!

Answer (score 2):

You can put several fields together inside parentheses, to be checked against rows in another set.

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM contracts c
  WHERE (c.cust, c.contractnbr) not in
    (SELECT m.cust, max(m.contractnbr)
       FROM contracts m
       GROUP BY cust
    )
```

This concept is probably most useful with `IN` as shown above, but can also be used in other queries to `JOIN`

```
FROM a JOIN b ON (a.x,a.y,a.z) = (b.x,b.y,b.z)
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
T2.CONTRACTNUMBER < MAX(T1.CONTRACTNUMBER)
```

with

```
T2.CONTRACTNUMBER NOT IN (SELECT MAX(T3.CONTRACTNUMBER)
                            from Contracts t3 
                            WHERE T3.CUST=T2.CUST)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that syntax has worked - the Incorrect use of MAX turned out to be a red herring as it occurred with your syntax too. However, it turns out that despite 'looking' like a number the field is actually stored as a string, so i had to wrap the field using CAST and that sorted it!

Comment: Look again at the subselect.  How can you select max(t1.anything) from t3?

Comment: forgot to change it when i pasted what he had.